# How to compare classifiers trained on features with missing data?

Tags: machine-learning, classification, missing-data, feature-selection

Let's say I have a training data set with two numeric features **A** and **B** and *n* samples, which are all labeled in binary fashion (binary classification problem).

```
   A    B   Label
   -------- -----
0  0.1  0.9     x
1  0.7  NaN     x
2  0.3  NaN     y
3  0.1  0.2     x
...
n  0.1  0.3     y
```

Also assume that feature **A** has no missing values, whereas feature **B** contains *m* missing values (shown as `NaN`, *m* > 0).

Now, I want to train a classifier on each feature individually to see which works best. For comparison, I use the standard evaluation metrics derived from the confusion matrix.

The problem is that some frameworks such as *scikit learn* do not allow `NaN` values so I have to get rid of them, either by discarding them or by imputing values.

Let's say I discard all *m* `NaN` values of feature **B**. Then I train a classifier on feature **A** with *n* samples, whereas I train the same classifier on feature **B** with only *n - m* samples. Of course, both yield the standard evaluation metrics but I cannot directly compare them anymore, or can I?

If I impute missing values, I get the same number of samples. But if there are many missing values, then this is a problem in itself as the data become less reliable.

My question now is how to actually make a sound comparison of a classifier which was trained on a feature without missing data with a classifier which was trained on a feature *with* (potentially much) missing data?

Any help is much appreciated!

Comment: You can try replacing Nans with a fixed value which is of the same type of other values in column but still distinct (For example, if your column is numeric with range 0-10, put -10 or 100 in missing values). That way you are forcing the model to treat those values somewhat different than others (of course that will depend on the model). This is one of the trade-off you will have to make if you want to use rows with missing values. Anyways, since this question is not about programming, but algorithmic approach, [Cross-validation](https://stats.stackexchange.com) will be better for this.

Answer (score 1):

You could replace all NaN values with a static number and then run a univariate feature selector over it. Concrete:

build a predictive model for each individual variable, and measure the performance of each model

Example:

```
from sklearn.cross_validation import cross_val_score, ShuffleSplit
from sklearn.datasets import load_boston
from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestRegressor

boston = load_boston()
X = boston["data"]
Y = boston["target"]
names = boston["feature_names"]

rf = RandomForestRegressor(n_estimators=20, max_depth=4)
scores = []
for i in range(X.shape[1]):
     score = cross_val_score(rf, X[:, i:i+1], Y, scoring="r2",
                              cv=ShuffleSplit(len(X), 3, .3))
     scores.append((round(np.mean(score), 3), names[i]))
print(sorted(scores, reverse=True))
```

So you can roughly see how the performance of each variable affects the target variable (knowing that you have replaced one of the feature NaN values)

Answer (score 0):

Missing values is a common problem, and there are several ways to handle that as you have mentioned some. 
There is indeed problem when you try to substitute some arbitrary values. 
Often NaN is substituted by 0 or the column mean, but that depends on what the data represents. 
In your case, one way could be to predict those values using ML if just one column has the missing data, and still it depends on how sensitive your data is.